# Group the dataframe based on their ids and stick the values of ids to each other with the same values of the day before or the dayafter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame, I want to group the data based on the ids and then stick the values for each id together. However, since the number of the ids are not equal, I have to fill the missing values for those **ids** with **same values** of the day before (**or the day after**) of **those ids**. I previously ask this question and I got a response, however it is only for the day before. But, in my real data, since some times I don't have the first day, their values are Nan.

I have provided an example as below, for example, for **id=1, id=2 there is two dates, but for id=3**, there are three days.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [1, 1, 2,2, 3, 3, 3]
df['date'] = ['2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-01','2019-01-02', '2019-01-01',      '2019-01-02','2019-01-03']
df['val1']  = [10, 100, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
df['val2']  = [30, 30, -20, -30, -40,-50, -60 ]
df['val3']  = [50, 10, 120, 300, 140, 150, 160]
```

The desired output is:

```
    val0  val1   val2  val3  val4   val5   val6  val7   val8
id                                                          
1   10.0  30.0   50.0  10.0  30.0   50.0  100.0  30.0   10.0
2   20.0 -20.0  120.0  30.0 -30.0  300.0   30.0 -30.0  300.0
3   40.0 -40.0  140.0  50.0 -50.0  150.0   60.0 -60.0  160.0
```

Here is the response for the case where it is for the day before.

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['id'].unique(), df['date'].unique()], names=['id', 'date'])
df = df.set_index(['id', 'date']).reindex(mi).sort_index().ffill()
df = df.groupby(level='id').apply(np.ravel).apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('val')
```

If you run the code, you can see that the **first values for the id=1 are Nan**.
And also I don't want to sort the id.

Can anybody help me with that? Thanks

Comment: @corralien: I don't know that you can see this question or not, but probably you know this question. Since the last time that I asked, you answer me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `pivot` the DataFrame, then use `groupby` across columns to fill in the missing values:

```
val_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('val')]
out = (df.pivot('id', 'date', val_cols)
       .groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1))
       .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
out.columns = [f'val{i}' for i in range(out.shape[1])]
```

Output:

```
    val0  val1   val2  val3  val4   val5   val6  val7   val8
id                                                          
1   10.0  30.0   50.0  10.0  30.0   50.0  100.0  30.0   10.0
2   20.0 -20.0  120.0  30.0 -30.0  300.0   30.0 -30.0  300.0
3   40.0 -40.0  140.0  50.0 -50.0  150.0   60.0 -60.0  160.0
```

Comment: Thanks. In my real data, I have thousand columns. There is any way to do the `['val1','val2','val3']` with a systematic way?

Comment: @Sadcow do they all start as `val...`?

Comment: Yes. All of them started with val.