# How to concatenate the values of a dataframe along column axis and fill missing values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I really stuck in this problem for a long time.

I have a data frame, I want to group the data based on the ids and then stick the values for each id together. However, since the number of the ids are not equal, I have to fill the missing values for those **ids** with **same values** of the day before (**or the day after**) of **those ids**. I previously ask this question and I got the response for that.

Here is the last question : [Group the dataframe based on their ids and stick the values of ids to each other with the same values of the day before or the dayafter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71888412/group-the-dataframe-based-on-their-ids-and-stick-the-values-of-ids-to-each-other)

Here is the code that I am using for my data.

```py
df = pd.read_csv("df_1.csv")
val_cols = df.filter(like="value_").columns
DF_new = (
    df.pivot("id", "date", val_cols)
    .groupby(level=0, axis=1)
    .apply(lambda x: x.ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1))
    .sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
)
DF_new.columns = [f"val{i}" for i in range(DF_new.shape[1])]
DF_new = DF_new.reset_index()
DF_new
```

But, when I want to test this on my real data, it does not provide the result that I want. It should started with 1, 2, 3, 4, ... but, here it started from 1, 10, ...

[image]

Here is a sample of my data (also I will put the link  in the comment)

I have provided a simple example as below, for example, for **id=1, id=2 there are two dates, but for id=3**, there are three days.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [1, 1, 2,2, 3, 3, 3]
df['date'] = ['2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-01','2019-01-02', '2019-01-01',      '2019-01-02','2019-01-03']
df['val1']  = [10, 100, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
df['val2']  = [30, 30, -20, -30, -40,-50, -60 ]
df['val3']  = [50, 10, 120, 300, 140, 150, 160]
```

```py
print(df)
   id        date  val0  val1  val2
0   1  2019-01-02    10    30    50
1   1  2019-01-03   100    30    10
2   2  2019-01-01    20   -20   120
3   2  2019-01-02    30   -30   300
4   3  2019-01-01    40   -40   140
5   3  2019-01-02    50   -50   150
6   3  2019-01-03    60   -60   160
```

The desired output is:

```
    val0  val1   val2  val3  val4   val5   val6  val7   val8
id                                                          
1   10.0  30.0   50.0  10.0  30.0   50.0  100.0  30.0   10.0
2   20.0 -20.0  120.0  30.0 -30.0  300.0   30.0 -30.0  300.0
3   40.0 -40.0  140.0  50.0 -50.0  150.0   60.0 -60.0  160.0
```

The provided code can work with this easy example.

Can anybody help me with that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [j for i in sorted(df["id"].unique()) for j in [i] * 3],
        "date": sorted(df["date"].unique()) * 3,
    }
)
temp_df = (
    pd.merge(left=temp_df, right=df, how="left", on=["id", "date"])
    .sort_values(by=["id", "date"])
    .drop(columns="date")
)

dfs = []
for i in sorted(df["id"].unique()):
    dfs.append(
        temp_df.loc[temp_df["id"] == i, :].fillna(method="bfill").fillna(method="ffill")
    )
temp_df = pd.concat(dfs)

dfs = []
for i in sorted(df["id"].unique()):
    rows = {j: row for j, row in temp_df.loc[temp_df["id"] == i, :].iterrows()}
    dfs.append(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(row).T for row in rows.values()], axis=1))

final_df = pd.concat(dfs)

final_df.columns = [
    f"val{i}" if col != "id" else col for i, col in enumerate(final_df.columns)
]

final_df = final_df.loc[:, ~final_df.columns.duplicated()].drop_duplicates(keep="last")

final_df["id"] = final_df["id"].fillna(method="ffill").astype(int)

dfs = []
for i in sorted(final_df["id"].unique()):
    dfs.append(
        final_df.loc[final_df["id"] == i, :]
        .fillna(method="bfill")
        .fillna(method="ffill")
    )
final_df = pd.concat(dfs).drop_duplicates().set_index("id")
final_df.columns = [f"val{i}" for i in range(final_df.shape[1])]
```

```py
print(final_df)
# Output
    val0  val1   val2  val3  val4   val5   val6  val7   val8
id
1   10.0  30.0   50.0  10.0  30.0   50.0  100.0  30.0   10.0
2   20.0 -20.0  120.0  30.0 -30.0  300.0   30.0 -30.0  300.0
3   40.0 -40.0  140.0  50.0 -50.0  150.0   60.0 -60.0  160.0
```